# Code for TensorFlow's EfficientNet preprocess_input()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using `EfficientNet` and I want to remove TensorFlow dependencies from my code, and for this I want to make `preprocess_input` on my own.

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.efficientnet import preprocess_input
```

Can anyone tell me how to write `preprocess_input` function of efficientnet without using TensorFlow?

```
def preprocess_input():
    ......
    return
```

I found this repository so far.
https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/efficientnet.py But I am not able to understand the code.

Comment: Here is an example: https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/06fbeb0f16e1304f239b2296578d1c50b15a983a/keras_applications/imagenet_utils.py#L18

Answer (score 1):

Efficient net model expect the images to have pixels in the range from 0 to 255 so if your images have pixels in that range you do not need to preprocess the input